# how can we open / launch download folder in flutter . As all web browser does when downloading is completed

Tags: android, flutter, download

As i have flutter application which downloads file from server using dio in public download folder. I want to navigate user to download folder as download is completed . I have seen solution android is using `startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));` but i didn't able to get for flutter .

Answer (score 0):

I think this package is what you are looking for [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent)

Comment: elaborate please. how?

Comment: AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
                action: 'android.intent.action.VIEW_DOWNLOADS',
              );
              await intent.launch();